# How to send mysql queries sequentially using express in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, async-await

I wrote the following code, where I have a post request that executes 2 queries and some other operations:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    dbController.query(
        "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'myUserName'",
        (err, result) => {
            console.log('<---- 1 ---->')
        }
    )
    // do something
    console.log('<---- 2 ---->')
    // do something
    dbController.query(
        "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'myUserName'",
        (err, result) => {
            console.log('<---- 3 ---->')
    })
    res.send('ok')
})
```

I want to execute all instructions inside the function sequentially, so instead of getting this output (which is the one I get after executing the code):

```
<---- 2 ---->
<---- 1 ---->
<---- 3 ---->
```

I wanna get this one:

```
<---- 1 ---->
<---- 2 ---->
<---- 3 ---->
```

Note that after adding the keyword `async` to the function and `await` to the queries, nothing changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you give `dbController.query` a callback function `(err, result) => {...}` as third parameter, it does *not* return a promise, but instead invokes the callback asynchronously. If you wrap `dbController.query` in [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal), you get a function that returns a promise which

- either resolves to `result`, which you can `await`,
- or rejects as `err`, which you can `catch`.

The two flavors are functionally equivalent, but with `util.promisify`, you can use `async` and `await`:

```js
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  var queryPromise = util.promisify(dbController.query.bind(dbController));
  try {
    var result = await queryPromise("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'myUserName'")
    console.log('<---- 1 ---->')
    console.log('<---- 2 ---->')
    result = await queryPromise("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'myUserName'")
    console.log('<---- 3 ---->')
    res.send('ok')
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
})
```

(Many other database client libraries offer the promise flavor out of the box.)

Comment: Sorry, [`mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) does _not_ offer the promise flavor directly, but you can achieve it with `util.promisify`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your logic in a `.then()`
Your code should look something like this:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    dbController.query(
        "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = myUserName",
        (err, result) => {
            console.log('<---- 1 ---->')
        }
    ). then(async function(rows){
// do something
    console.log('<---- 2 ---->')
    // do something
})
dbController.query(
        "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = myUserName",
        (err, result) => {
            console.log('<---- 3 ---->')
    })
    res.send('ok')
})
```

You might also need to wrap the second query in a `.then()`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but this will not work because: 
`TypeError: dbController.query(...).then is not a function`